# Calculating Area

Tags: geometry, area

We are asked to find the area of the shaded portion. The shaded portion consists of the whole right triangle subtracted by the white rectangle within the right triangle. The dimensions for the right triangle are base $6x$ and height $8x+2$. The dimension on the rectangle is width $x$ and length $3x+1$.

What is the area of the shaded portion? No units are needed to represent the measurements.

[image]

Comment: I think we're going to need a diagram to learn the relative orientations of the triangle and rectangle.

Comment: I don't have a diagram or an image. Is there any way I can something like this?

Comment: Oh, I know! I'll just send the link to the screenshot.

Comment: That'll do.  Once you do that I can inline the image.

Comment: So the area of a triangle is b*h/2 and the area of a rectangle is b*h. All we do is find the area of the triangle and then subtract the area of the rectangle. But there's some algebra I need to solve.

Comment: The algebra is a matter of simplifying the expressions, to collect the $x^2$ terms, the $x$ terms, and the constant terms.  But yes, that's basically what you need to do.

Comment: How is this not amenable to being solved per simple algebraic manipulation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The area of the triangle is $\frac{Bh}{2}$ where $B$ is the base of the triangle, and $h$ is the height.

The area of the rectangle is $lw$. $l$ is the base of the rectangle and $w$ is the height of the triangle.

Subtract one from the other, so the area of the shaded part is then $\frac{Bh}{2}-lw$.

Now plug in the original values and solve.

$$\frac{Bh}{2}-lw$$

$$=\frac{(6x)(8x+2)}{2}-(3x+1)(x)$$

$$=\frac{(6x \cdot 8x+6x \cdot 2)}{2}-(3x+1)(x)$$

$$=\frac{48x^2+12x}{2}-(3x+1)(x)$$

$$=24x^2+6x-(3x+1)(x)$$

$$=24x^2+6x-(3x \cdot x+1 \cdot x)$$

$$=24x^2+6x-(3x^2+x)$$

$$=24x^2+6x-3x^2-x$$

$$=21x^2+5x$$

There, you have the answer. If something is unclear, please leave a comment.

Answer (score 3):

Simply find the area of the triangle ($A=\frac{1}{2}bh$) and subtract the area of the rectangle ($A=lw$).

So, the area of the shaded portion would be $\frac{1}{2}(6x)(8x+2) - x(3x+1)$. Can you solve from here?

Comment: Unfortunately not.

Comment: Do you know the distributive property of multiplication over addition?  We have $a(b+c) = a \times b + a \times c$.  Does that help?

Comment: Ok, so for (6x)(8x+2) we have (6x)(8x+2)=(6x)(8x)+(6x)(2)=48x+12x, right? And because we have 1/2 we can divide the whole expression by two?

Comment: 48x+12x=60x and (60x) multiplied by 1/2 is 30x.

Comment: Oh, ok. And that leaves us with x(3x+1)=x(3x)+x(1)=4x+1x and not forgetting the 30x .... 30x-4x+1x=27x. So 27 x is the area of the shaded portion/answer?

Comment: Isn't it $21x^2+5x$? $(6x)(8x+2)=(6x)(8x)+(6x)(2)=48x^2+12x$. You missed the square.

Comment: The square ... I see. And there's another problem. Let's say I did (1/2)3x first. I get a different answer.

Comment: Then my whole answer is wrong because we can't add 48x^2+12x. And I think that I'm supposed to do (1/2)(6x) first.

Comment: Let me redo this: 1/2(6x)(8x+2)-x(3x+1)=3x(8x+2)-x(3x+1)=24x^2+6x-4x+1x=24x^2-3x. Is that it?

Comment: I got it. Done.

Comment: It's 24x^2+6x..

Answer (score 1):

**Basic approach.** The area of a rectangle is length times width.  The area of a right triangle is one leg times the other leg, divided by $2$ (because if one leg is the base, the other leg is the altitude).  Subtract the rectangle's area from the triangle's area, and there's your answer.  Do you see why?

Comment: Yes, I know about that part. But I get stuck where I have to simplify the equation.

Comment: The fact that you know that part would have been useful to put in your original post, as part of the context.

Comment: You're correct. I was just looking for the answer.

Comment: I need help with solving the equation.

Comment: Without an equal sign, there is no equation.

Comment: @SenexÆgyptiParvi: He has been using "equation" to refer to the expression.